# what will be output of this shopify script?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

```html
<pre>
<!-- viewing /collections page with collection title of "A", "B", "C", "D" -->
{% assign colletion_titles = collections | map: 'title' %}
{{ colletion_titles }}
 </pre>
```

What output would this liquid be?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The variable "*colletion_titles*" would be array.
All values will be printed like this:

```
ABCD
```

If you want to add commas between the titles, just add a  | join: ", "
like this:

```
{{ colletion_titles | join: ", " }}
```